# Compile slim to html from string?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to do this in Ruby, not from shell or through a loader system.

Something like how in ERB you can do `ERB.new("<%= 'hello' %>").result(binding) == "hello"`

```
slim_string = "a href='#' home"
html = # ????
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
Slim::Template.new { "a href='#' home" }.render
```